# Не удалось установить Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi при установке Visula Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Новичок в программировании. Пытался установить Visual Studio Community 2022, но установка завершилась не  полностью с сообщением "не удалось установить Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi". После установки в Visual Studio нет вообще никаких проектов, ни консольных, ни WPF и других. Переустановки не помогают. Пытался зайти в файлы программы и найти Shared.Msi, но безуспешно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://minirex.ru/ne-udalos-ustanovit-microsoft-visual-studio-community-shared-msi/